# Scrapy only groups of items when I run this code

Tags: scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and I've a problem getting it to return more than the first row. This is the code:

```py
        import scrapy

        class FarmtoolsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'farmtools'
        allowed_domains = ['www.donedeal.ie']
        start_urls = ['https://www.donedeal.ie/farmtools/']

        def parse(self, response):
            for row in response.xpath('//ul[@class="card-collection"]'):
                yield {
                    'item_title': response.xpath('.//div[1]/p[@class="card__body- 
                      title"]/text()').get(),
                    'item_county': response.xpath('.//ul[@class="card__body- 
                       keyinfo"]/li[2]/text()').get(),
                    'item_price': 
                  response.xpath('.//p[@class="card__price"]/span[1]/text()').get(),
                    'item_id': response.xpath('.//li[@class="card- 
                     item"]/a/@href').get()
                      }
```

I would like it to have Title, County, Price, Id of each item in different rows. Actually if I run this code as it is it just gives me the first line.
I have tried getall but that just gives me blocks of each item.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code which returns 30 rows:

```py
class FarmtoolsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'farmtools'
    allowed_domains = ['www.donedeal.ie']
    start_urls = ['https://www.donedeal.ie/farmtools/']

    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//ul[@class="card-collection"]/li') 

        for row in rows:
            yield {
                'item_title': row.xpath('.//div[1]/p[@class="card__body-title"]/text()').get(),
                'item_county': row.xpath('.//ul[@class="card__body-keyinfo"]/li[2]/text()').get(),
                'item_price': row.xpath('.//p[@class="card__price"]/span[1]/text()').get(),
                'item_id': row.xpath('.//li[@class="card-item"]/a/@href').get()
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

try **row**.xpath('.// ) instead of response.xpath

eg

```
for row in response.xpath('//ul[@class="card-collection"]'):
    yield {'item_title': row.xpath('.//div[1]/p[@class="card__body- 
              title"]/text()').get(), etc...}
```